# Overruling chart.style.nodeDisplay in nodeRule in zoomcharts

Tags: zoomcharts

I have use nodeRules to set specific styling for nodes depending on the type of node. Now looking for a way to overrule nodeDisplay settings. What I want to achieve is that when there is no node.image available, that it shows the label.

in my chart I have :

```
            style:{
                nodeRules:{"rule1":nodeStyle},
                linkRules:{"rule1":linkStyle},
                linkLabel:{textStyle:{font:"12px Arial", fillColor: "black"}, backgroundStyle:{fillColor:"#FFF", lineColor:"black"}},
                makeImagesCircular:true,
                nodeDisplay:"image"
            },
```

in my nodeStyle function, I would like to have something like this:

```
            case "organization":
                node.radius = 40;
                node.fillColor = "red";
                node.lineColor = "red";
                node.labelStyle= {textStyle:{font:"14px Arial",fillColor:"black"}};

                $.ajax({
                    url:'/img/'+node.id+'.png',
                    type:'HEAD',
                    error: function()
                    {


                      // here the chart's nodeDisplay settings would be overruled

                      node.display="roundtext";




                    },
                    success: function()
                    {
                        node.image= "/img/"+node.id+".png";
                    }
                });                    
                break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the nodeDisplay is a global setting, not customizable per node.

Per node display type will certainly be implemented as we develop the chart.